# Pressing a radio button twice, calculates twice

Tags: java, android

In my code if the user presses the radio button twice it will calculate the value twice.  How can I prevent this?  I am using a switch statement inside a onClick.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    double value;
    NumberFormat myMileFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    NumberFormat myMeterFormat = new DecimalFormat("0000");

    String stringEmptyCheck = edit_distance.getText().toString();

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_minusDis:
        decrementLength();
        break;

    case R.id.button_plusDis:
        incrementLength();
        break;

    case R.id.button_done:
        this.finish();
        break;

    case R.id.radio_miles:
        if (stringEmptyCheck.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Miles or meters cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            value = 3.50;
            edit_distance.setText(myMileFormat.format(value));
        } else {

            value = Double.parseDouble(edit_distance.getText().toString());
            if ((value /= 1609.00) > DistanceInterval.MAX_LENGTH_MILES) {
                value = DistanceInterval.MAX_LENGTH_MILES;
            }

            edit_distance.setText(myMileFormat.format(value));

        }
        break;
```

Comment: If the radio button is already checked, add some logic to detect if it's already checked and then don't re-compute if it is. An onClick event will fire anytime it's clicked, not just if the radio button is not checked.

Comment: I understand the logic of checking to see if something has been checked by using if(radio_miles.isChecked()) but how will you check if it is clicked again without stopping the first initial go around?  Where would you suggest putting the logic statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean to check if the button has been pressed once already, and if it has, the calculations will not be calculated again(by setting the boolean to true). Once the calculations have finished, and whatever you want to happen before the user can press the button has happened, you can set that boolean back to false. All you need is a simple if statement and a boolean variable.